# strange unsigned char casting

Tags: c

What is the purpose / advantage / difference of using

```
/* C89 compliant way to cast 'char' to 'unsigned char'. */
static inline unsigned char
to_uchar (char ch)
{
  return ch;
}
```

versus a standard cast ?

Edit :
Found in a base64 code in [gnulib](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gnulib/gnulib/lib/base64.c?rev=HEAD)

Comment: It's not really an answer, but the only difference I can think of is that calling this function on any data-type other than `char` should be equivalent to a double cast, i.e. `(unsigned char)(char)`.  I don't see what effect that can have, though.

Comment: Tell us something about where you found this, we don't have enough information. The reference to C89 is completely strange.

Comment: The funny thing is that the functional cast is already build-in in the language.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: can you elaborate on what you mean by functional cast?

Comment: @Jens: It seems to be a remarkably omnipresent code snippet: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22C89+compliant+way+to+cast%22

Comment: This code is just idiotic. There's no purpose. If you're finding it all over the place, as Oli pointed out, it's probably just a case of idiots copying idioms without understanding why they're bogus.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: amazing. From what the use is I can only see that they'd like to have a functional cast. Or maybe in times there were some compilers barking at you when you converted a `char` to an `unsigned char` if `char` was a signed type. `base64.c` is so old we need a historian.

Comment: The `inline` keyword even makes it *not* C89 compliant.

Comment: @Jens: I got it wrong, it's included only in C++, I think to extend the constructor-syntax for temporaries also to built-in types (and AFAIK it doesn't work with unsigned types because they are composed of two words).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the programmer who wrote the function doesn't like the cast syntax ...

```
foo(to_uchar(ch));      /* function call */
foo((unsigned char)ch); /* cast */
```

But I'd let the compiler worry about it anyway :)

```
void foo(unsigned char);
char s[] = "bar";
foo(s[2]); /* compiler implicitly casts the `s[2]` char to unsigned char */
```

Answer (score 1):

### Purpose

To:

- Cast from `char` to `unsigned char`
- Do more with the cast than from a conventional cast
- Open your mind to the possibilities of customized casting between other types and select from the advantages below for those also

### Advantage

One could:

- Break on these kinds of casts when debugging
- Track and quantify the use of casts through profiling tools
- Add limits checking code (pretty grim for `char` conversions but potentially very useful for larger/smaller type casts)
- Have delusions of grandeur
- There is a single point of casting, allowing you to carefully analyze and modify what code is generated
- You could select from a range of casting techniques based on the environment (for example in C++ you could use `numeric_limits<>`)
- The cast is explicit and will never generate warnings (or at least you can force choke them in one place)

### Difference

- Slower with poor compilers or good compilers with the necessary optimization flags turned off
- The language doesn't force consistency, you might not notice you've forgotten to use the cast in places
- Kind of strange, and Java-esque, one should probably accept and study C's weak typing and deal with it case by case rather than trying to conjure special functions to cope